# Ruby on Rails: Treat deprecation warnings as errors or otherwise find deprecated code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecated

I recently upgraded from Rails 2 to Rails 3, and I'm trying to root out all the code I might have that is deprecated. The way I'm doing this is just surfing around a copy of my site running on a development machine, and peering at the output from the console for warnings.

Is there a way to cause Rails to treat deprecation warnings as errors or otherwise find deprecated code more efficiently?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can customise the behaviour of deprecated calls by setting `ActiveSupport::Deprecation.behavior`. This should be set to a `Proc` that accepts a message and a callstack e.g. you could do:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.behavior = Proc.new { |message, callstack|
  raise message + "\n" + callstack.join("\n  ")
}
```

If you have automated tests for your app these are invaluable when upgrading the version of Rails being used.

Comment: Where `Proc` has to be located?

Comment: @Iván you could put this in a file of its own in `config/initializers` e.g. `deprecation.rb`. Also note in more recent versions of Rails, if you'd like to raise an exception on deprecated calls you can use `ActiveSupport::Deprecation.behavior = :raise` and don't need to write a `Proc` yourself.

Comment: It´s very clear, especially because I am using RoR 5. Thanks @mikej