# How do I get rid of the rails3 warning: DEPRECATION WARNING: RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER is deprecated

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the full warning:

DEPRECATION WARNING: RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER is deprecated. Please use ::Rails.logger. (called from  at /Users/timmartin/src/edcaliber/config/environment.rb:7)

My tree does not contain 'RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER' and line 7 of environment.rb is just:

MyApplication::Application.initialize!

How can I get rid of this warning? I recently upgraded from rails2

Answer (score 0):

That's probably from one of the plugins you are using. Dig around and see if you can find which one it is.

Comment: Thanks, I have some plugins in my Gemile. Any suggestions for a good way to track down which one the message is coming from?

Comment: If it's not a long list of gems, just remove them until it goes away. I saw a pull request on the RPM gem that has this issue as well, for example.

Comment: Oh, and there's also this question here that might help you ferret it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648222/ruby-on-rails-treat-deprecation-warnings-as-errors-or-otherwise-find-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Got the same warning message on my Rails 3 app, where I had explicitly used RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER in one of the files; replacing it with ::Rails.logger made the warning message go away.

Looks like there might be an instance of RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER in one of the other config files in your app. Try finding for that string in your app.

Running the following command from your rails app home directory should show you where it is.

`grep -r RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER *`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't look like it. That command gives no results. I think it's in a plugin/gem as Robert suggested. Not sure the best way to track it down though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in your code, it's in a gem somewhere. Here's a bash one-liner to search your gems:

```
find `gem environment | grep "INSTALLATION DIR" | cut -d: -f2` | grep rb$ | xargs grep RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER
```

For me it looked like webrat, railties, and newrelic are all using RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.

If you'd like to learn how to fish instead of just eating this fish, or you don't just paste scripts into a terminal when some guy on the internet tells you to, here's how to do it step-by-step yourself. First run

```
gem environment
```

to see where your gems' ruby code gets installed. For me, that directory appeared to be listed as "INSTALLATION DIRECTORY" and it was `/home/lacker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352` . The next step is to get a listing of all the files ending in "rb" in those gems:

```
find /home/lacker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352 | grep rb$
```

Now we want to grep each of those for RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER, which you can use xargs + grep for:

```
find /home/lacker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352 | grep rb$ | xargs grep RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER
```

You can also use [Ack](http://betterthangrep.com) for this, if you have that installed.

Comment: Thanks! It was actually in new_relic and is gone now! :)